# rspec , 2 way is the same?

Tags: rspec, rspec2, rspec-rails

```
@sponge = Factory(:user)
let(:event_type) { EventType.where( name: 'visit_site').first
```

**ONE:** => false when run test

```
subject{ Event.new user: @sponge, event_type: event_type, points_earned: event_type.points_value, description: {}}

context 'call #update_user_points when create a event' do
   it{should_receive(:update_user_points)}
end
```

**TWO:** => true when run test

```
it 'should call update_user_points after creation' do
   event = Event.new user: @sponge, event_type: event_type, points_earned:event_type.points_value, description: {}
   event.should_receive(:update_user_points)
   event.save
end
```

Give me some advises please :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your second example is not the same as your first: they both set up a message expectation for `Event#update_user_points`, but the second calls `save` after that; the first doesn't.

I don't think you can use `should_receive` with an implicit subject, as you try to do in the first example. rspec doesn't seem to complain, but I don't think it does what you're wanting it to. In order, it does this:

1. Runs the subject block to instantiate an Event.
2. Sets up a message expectation saying that the subject (the newly created event) should receive the the `update_user_points` method.
3. Then it stops, because the example has nothing beyond that.

It fails because the message was never received.

Comment: I understand a litte in rspec, example why we must place "should_receive" before "event.save". I think It run update_user_points after a event created , It should place after that? And I though the first way must run fine?
can you lead me something good to learn about rspec for beginner. 
thank you :D